# Media conversion within Backoffice

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Is it possible to convert media within `Backoffice` in Hybris? Or is it a functionality supported only in Hybris Management Console?

Comment: You question not clear. hybris using imagemagic for media conversions. Also you can call this service in backoffice.

Comment: I was wondering if there is any action button for medias to convert them from a type to another one in backoffice. And triggering that button will display a wizard widget or some menu..

Comment: I am not sure there is button for it. We generally use it while importing medias first time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mediaconversion` extension which uses ImageMagick

https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/8b3669cc86691014b42abc07ad88d80f.html?version=1905&locale=en-US

Comment: Please include a demonstration as to [how this tool solves the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251602/recommending-off-site-resources-when-questions-dont-ask-for-it/251605#251605) as part of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need the `mediaconversionbackoffice` Extension in your project.
Then you should get a button to convert missing media in a media container with a conversion group and a main image defined.